# OnLoad Only Called Once With Document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, onload

In my JS file, I'm trying to create a list from a JavaScript array. Obviously, you can't do `document.getElementId` before the page has loaded since the JS is called first. The if statement produces three results, but only one is loaded because of the `window.onload` function.

```
var getDateContent = function(year,month,date){         
    if(contentObj != null && contentObj[year] != null && 
        contentObj[year][month] != null && 
        contentObj[year][month][date] != null){

        var contentObjArray = contentObj[year][month][date];
        window.onload=function(){
            var items = document.getElementById("test");
            for (var i = 0; i < contentObjArray.length; i++ ) {
                var item = document.createElement("li");
                item.innerHTML = contentObjArray[i];
                items.appendChild(item);
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

I guess my question is, how can I access the element id without `window.onload`? This is because `window.onload` only runs once when I need it to run multiple times

Comment: You should put  the "window.onload=function(){" at the start of your entire JavaScript file (and move the "}" appropriately). Then, within that larger block, you can call your inner function as often as you want.

Comment: @jasonhansel that would make complete sense, except most of the js file has to be run before that.

Comment: @jasonhansel the JS file is basically injecting things into the html which doesn't work after `onload`

Comment: Why? If your issue is that the JS won't run until image files load, you can just put the <script> tag before the end of the body element rather than in the <head>

Comment: Injecting things into the HTML should generally be avoided for performance reasons, and because (eg in your example) it makes dealing with OnLoad harder. It would be better to use the innerHTML property of a DOM element.

Comment: @jasonhansel There are no image files. The whole point is that `document.getElementById` won't work until the HTML has rendered yet it constantly updates.

Comment: @jasonhansel That's how it's built. That's the only way it works. I'm asking for a solution to my problem.

Comment: I tried doing the `window.onload` and then accessing the `document.getElementId` through a global variable, but that didn't work.

Comment: Figured it out. Using setTimeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead of assigning to the `onload` property.

```
addEventListener('load', function () { /* ... */ });
```

This will just add additional listeners instead of overwriting the previous one.

(You need a [shiv for IE8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Older_way_to_register_event_listeners))